# Oracle SQL Developer - Driver Class not found. Vendor code 0

Tags: jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL V. 4.1.3.

I have installed it successfully, and established connections to our database. I see the db connections, but when expanding them this error message shows up:

> Driver Class not found. Verify the Driver location. Vendor Code 0

I installed Ms JDBC driver 6.0 for SQL Server and unpacked it in my ProgramFiles. I then went to ControlPanel-SystemProperties and added the sqljdbc42.jar as `<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc.jar` under my existing environment variable called PATH.

Now when I go to SQL Developer Properties, I see JDBC.JAR added to Java.library.path but not to java.class.path. Is this the reason I am still getting error message? How do I go about fixing it? Or is there some other issue at hand?

Comment: we don't support the MS JDBC driver for SQL Server, see Pravin's answer before for getting jtds and using the preferences to register it.

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced the reported error. It appears one can go to preferences of a connection, click on 'Test' to test the connection and then it suddenly works again... Very strange, but it worked. You do have to do this for all connections, but hey, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Need to set driver path inside Preference -> Database -> 3rd Party JDBC driver -- in case of mssql add -- jtds-1.3.1.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was just little stupid. All I had to do was add Third Party JDBC Driver path under Preferences in SQL Developer and it works like a Charm.